# Secure point to point remote access to NAS drive

Tags: encryption, authentication, network, windows, vpn

This question is very similar but also distinctly different ([How do I ensure data encryption on Samba transmission on *NIX systems?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/9159/57325))

I'm looking to set up remote access to a NAS unit locally sharing via samba. I'd like to set up access on a remote PC (all windows) that would see the NAS unit as a mapped network drive.

From what I understand I have two options (I'm open to more this is just all I am aware of at the moment):

1. Set up a dynamic IP hostname, forward the necessary ports, and map the net work drive on the remote system. (how much of this is encrypted/secure?)
2. Set up a VPN server and have the user connect to my network to have access to the mapped network drive. (should encrypt everything)

Option 2 would be the obvious choice however I don't want all of the network traffic on the remote PC to also go through the VPN. I want *only* the mapped network drive interactions to go through the VPN. Is this possible? Is another approach better for achieving this?

In addition I don't want the remote PC to have to manually connect/disconnect to gain access, and furthermore, they may have an existing VPN they are already routing through. Am I asking for too much?

If it matters, the NAS I have in mind is Synology.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method is SSHFS.

Your NAS server runs a SSH server which you then connect to from your remote machine. Leveraging SSHFS it will mount a drive on your remote machine via SSH (secure, encrypted) from the server you specify.

I've not used the windows client version so YMMV.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh

HTH

Comment: Superb, I'll have to give this a try.

Comment: i didnt notice in your original post, you may have to manually connect if there is a disconnect, im not up to speed on any autoconnecting ssh clients. just a fyi, YMMV

Comment: The Win GUI seems to map it to a drive letter so I'm guessing it falls back on however that gets handled on the OS level. It saves the info and probably auto-connects periodically if it was detected as disconnected.

Comment: Cool, hope it works out well for you. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work on Windows > 7 due to Dokan dependencies.